# Why do I get an -fpermissive error with this code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Why would the compiler complain at the indicated line?

```
class C
{
    std::string s;
public:
    C() { s = "<not set>";}
    ~C() {}
    void Set(const std::string ss) { s=ss; }
    const std::string Get() { return s; }

    C &operator=(const C &c) { Set(c.Get()); return *this; }
    //error: passing ‘const C’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const string C::Get()’
    // discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]


    //C &operator=(C &c) { Set(c.Get()); return *this; }   <-- works fine

};
```

Comment: `-fpermissive` is not an error, it is a flag to control generated errors.  See [What does the fpermissive flag do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843818/what-does-the-fpermissive-flag-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the function `Get()` to be `const`:

```
const std::string Get() const { return s; }
```

Even though `Get()` doesn't change any member values, the compiler is instructed to only let you call functions that are explicitly labeled `const`.

gcc is instructing you that you can override it's complaint by using the argument `-fpermissive`; however, it's generally better not to do this (or else why declare anything `const` at all?). Generally, it's better to make sure every member function called on a `const` parameter is a `const` member function.

This article concerning [Const Correctness](http://www.possibility.com/Cpp/const.html) is very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `operator =` object `c` is a constant object: it has `const C` type. In C++ language you are not allowed to call non-constant member functions of constant objects. I.e. calling `c.Get()` is illegal since your `Get` is a non-constant member function. This is why the compiler reports an error.

Either make your `c` non-constant (as in your commented-out version of the code), or make `Get` constant. It is up to you to decide which approach is right, but it looks like you should do the latter.

As a side note, there's not much point of declaring `Get()` as returning `const std::string`. If you were returning it by reference (as `const std::string &`) then that `const` would be appropriate. But since you are returning by value, declaring the return type as `const` is not that useful. It is a matter of your personal style though.

Comment: Regarding your sidenote: returning the string as a const value doesn't allow the string to be moved. That is, the value will use the copy constructor of std::string and not the move constructor since you can't cast const string to string&&.