# What are differences between fpermissive errors and others?

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors

There are few question in my mind, can you please help me?

1. What is meant of fpermissive error ?
2. What are differences between fpermissive errors and others ?
3. Are they depend on compiler?
4. If i use fpermissive flag to skip these errors, will it be problem for my app?

Thanks

Comment: Flags to a compiler (like `-fpermissive`) are *always* compiler-specific. And even if multiple compilers implement the same option, it might not mean the same thing. Lastly, silencing warnings or errors is like treating a bad disease by just ignoring it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the fpermissive flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843818/what-does-the-fpermissive-flag-do)